# Finding intersection points of a line and circle

Tags: geometry, functions, circles

Ok so this one's probably pretty simple but i don't see how to do it. I'm stuck on a question that involves finding the coordinates of points where a line meets a circle.

The exact question is: "Find the coordinates where the line y= x-3 meets the circle (x-4)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 25" I assume it's something to do with solving simultaneously and substituting, but if someone could just explain how to get to the answer (1,-2) and (8,5) it would be much appreciated.

Thanks to whoever can help :)

Comment: substitute y=x-3 into the equation of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $y=x-3$ into the equation for the circle to obtain: 
$$(x-4)^2+(x-5)^2=25$$
$$\implies 2x^2-18x+16=0$$
$$\implies x^2-9x+8=0$$
$$\implies (x-8)(x-1)=0$$
$$\implies x = 1,8$$

Comment: After this use y=x-3 to find y coordinate